# Coroutine and Retrofit crash after doing a lot of request

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm doing a lot of requests to get all players from a dummy API test.

```
https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?page=0
```

But when it reaches iteration 60, or 67 or something like that, the app crash with a null

```
suspend fun getAllPlayers(): PlayersNetworkModel {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val initMetaInfoResponse = api.getAllPlayers()

        var data: MutableList<DataNetworkModel> = mutableListOf()
        var meta = initMetaInfoResponse.body()?.meta

        while(meta?.currentPage!! < meta?.totalPages!! && meta?.nextPage != null){
            val recursiveResponse = api.getAllPlayers(meta?.nextPage!!)
            recursiveResponse.body()?.data?.let { results -> data.addAll(results) }
            meta = recursiveResponse.body()?.meta!!
        }

        PlayersNetworkModel(data, meta)
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Process: com.victormartin.archmvvm, PID: 14551 java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.victormartin.archmvvm.data.network.ApiService$getAllPlayers$2.invokeSuspend(ApiService.kt:28 undefined)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677 undefined)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664 undefined)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@c2e4a7e, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Why is it hanging if I do a lot of requests?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities in my eyes. First option is that this crash occurs because of the mess with using [the !! operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator) and somehow the `api.getAllPlayers(meta?.nextPage!!)` is getting `null`. I have just implemented some dummy code but it looks much clearer, see below.

```
data class PlayersData(
    val data: List<Data>,
    val meta: Meta
) {

    data class Data(
        val id: Int,
        val first_name: String
        // add more fields if needed
    )

    data class Meta(
        val total_pages: Int,
        val current_page: Int,
        val next_page: Int?,
        val per_page: Int,
        val total_count: Int
    )
}
```

And the get method:

```
private suspend fun getAllPlayers() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val resultsList = mutableListOf<PlayersData.Data>()
    var nextPage: Int? = 0
    while (nextPage != null) {
        val response = playersService.getAllPlayers(nextPage)
        resultsList.addAll(response.data)
        nextPage = response.meta.next_page
    }
}
```

I don't get any NullPointerException, however I get the:

```
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 429 Too Many Requests
```

which occurs after doing 60 requests - that's the second option. You probably just posted wrong error message. Try adjusting the code to avoid using the !! operator and then check the logs for the HTTP 429 error.

Finally, you shouldn't spam so many requests to get all of the data at once. It's paginated for some reason. You should rather load the next pages on demand, for example when the user will scroll the players list all the way down.